# Copy ZipEntry from one zip file to another zip file without decompressing

Tags: java, kotlin

In my Kotlin service. I have a zip file A, and I want to conditionally add the contents of zip file A to zip file B or C depending on the ZipEntry name.

Is there a way to avoid decompressing the ZipEntry and just “copy” the entry to the new zip files?

Edit;
I can use apache compress if it help achieve what I’m after.

Comment: To me it looks like accessing the compressed data is not possible per API design.

Answer (score 2):

In Java Path is a generalization of disk File. It works with **FileSystemViews**, and one such "file system" is the protocol `jar:file:`, for zip files. With `Files.copy(Path, Path)` you then can abstractly copy zip entries. *That is the most elegant way to go.*

However I doubt this prevents decompressing/compressing. **Parsing** the zip files oneself is probably *fastest*.

I would try both.